# view in thumbnail

Tags: cakephp

I want to view all files in thumbnail view using cakephp.how?

Comment: You need to be a little more details and clear.  Are these image files?  Where are they?  Etc.

Comment: are you talking about a specific IDE? pls detail.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a vague question, I'm going with the wild stab in the dark:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/search/3/thumbnail

I guess one of those should help you out..